# Merge all tables from SQLite3 database into one single pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I would like to undertake some anaylsis of the tables within my database. But to do this, first I need to merge my sqlite3 tables into one single pandas dataframe.

All the tables are identical in structure.

I would also like the dataframe to have the column headers at the top.

The link below touched on the subject slightly but doesn't really address my scenario:
[Merge tables from two different databases - sqlite3/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653267/merge-tables-from-two-different-databases-sqlite3-python)

Any help to help me merge my sqlite3 tables into one single pandas dataframe would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have just stumbled across a simple solution to my own question:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('name_of.db')

cur = conn.cursor()


cur.execute('INSERT INTO master_table SELECT * FROM table_name1)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO master_table SELECT * FROM table_name2)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO master_table SELECT * FROM table_name3)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO master_table SELECT * FROM table_name4)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO master_table SELECT * FROM table_name5)

conn.commit()

conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect('name_of.db')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM master_table;", conn)
```